# "Question about reading philosophy" Is it appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I apologize for asking this question in advance as it may seem a little narrow.

I was going to ask "How should one read philosophy?". While this may seem subjective at first, I am asking for a methodical answer and thus not an answer that is an opinion. For example, in math, it is recommended that you sit with a pencil/pen and paper and jot down ideas or try some examples/theorems/proofs as they come to you to increase how much you learn and understand. So, I want to ask a question that is similar to that.

> What is the recommended way to read philosophy?

Of course, you can't read it as a fiction book because it is very dense in ideas and material. So what it be appropriate? What should I tag it as (if it is)?

Comment: There is no unique way of reading philosophy (or math). I suggest you ask a bunch of more specific questions, such as: "how to read Nietzsche?", "how to read Wittgenstein?", "how to read Aristotle?", and so on. To these more specific questions there _may_ be more or less objective answers. But I'm not sure SE is an appropriate forum for getting answers to those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How should one read philosophy?

It depends on what you are trying to get out of it. I read things differently if I want to ace an exam vs. want to get an understanding deep enough to write a lit review, for example. Also, a technique might work for one person but not another. Some people prefer taking notes, others prefer highlighting, others still prefer to just read the whole thing through first, then go back, etc...

If I understand correctly, however, this META question is about whether the question "How should one read philosophy?" would be appropriate for the main site. The answer is **no it would not be**. As stated there is no "one way" to read philosophy. People will have their various strategies they can share with you, but such discussion is better suited for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium) as it is off-topic for the main site (and here as well, technically).

Comment: Okay sounds good. Thanks for the clarification!